# Get new Google OAuth Token when old one expires?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

I'm developing a chrome extension that uses Google's OAuth to get the user's name and be able to write something to a Google Spreadsheet.

I was able to do what I need but I noticed that every time I open the extension's page action (where the OAuth is being done), it renews and gives my extension a new token even if the old one is still not expired.

Ideally I need to somehow check and just before the old one expires, a new one is issued.  Currently if a user waits longer than 1 hour the extension becomes useless because it's still trying to use the old token.  They would have to click on the page action icon in the omnibar to refresh it and get a new token.

So my question is, how can I have it refresh and give the extension a new token when it's just about to expire?  I'm not trying to have the user click manually every 1 hour either so I can't figure that one out.

Here's the code that I have to do the OAuth:

**popup.html:**

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/contentscript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></script>
    </head>


<body style="width: 500px">

<div id="PleaseLogIn" style="display: none;" >
  <h2>Please sign in before using this extension!</h2>
</div>  


<center><span id="signinButton">
      <span
        class="g-signin"
        data-callback="signinCallback" 
        data-clientid=".....apps.googleusercontent.com"
        data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
        data-width="wide"
        data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds">
      </span>
    </span>
</center>


 </body>
</html>
```

**contentscript.js:**

```
 (function() {
     var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
     po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=signinCallback';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();

  function signinCallback(authResult) {
        if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {

                //hide the welcome text and sign in button if signed in.
                document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
                document.getElementById('PleaseLogIn').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');

                //I'm storing the token in chrome.local.storage to be used by the rest of the extension
                var token = JSON.stringify(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token);
                chrome.storage.local.set({'token': token});

                //get the logged in user name
                makeAPICall();

                //reload the current tab so it can pick up the user's name and their token
                chrome.tabs.reload();


        } else {

                //if the user is not logged in or there was an issue, let them know to log in
                document.getElementById('PleaseLogIn').setAttribute('style', 'display: ');
            console.log('Problem with sign in: ' + authResult['error']);
        }
  }

        //request info from the user's account such as their name
        function makeAPICall(){
        gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
          var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
          });

          request.execute(function (resp){

            var username = resp.displayName;

            chrome.storage.local.set({'username': username});

            });
       });
  }
```

I'm assuming I have to somehow check if the current token is expired or about to be, then get a new one and finally save it in chrome.local.storage for the extension to use next time it needs it.

P.S. I even tried Chrome.Identity and that does issue a new token but it can't be used until the whole extension is reloaded :/

Thank you!

Comment: The token returned from `getToken()` contains a property `expires_in`. see - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#OAuth20TokenObject

Comment: You might want to check out the [Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity).

Comment: @abraham Thanks, I tried that already actually and while it does work, the extension won't pick up the new token until after I reload the whole extension from chrome://extensions.  I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or missing something but I'd love to use that method if possible.

Comment: You can call `getAuthToken` in silent mode anytime you want in your extension to get the token. E.g. use an alarm or setTimeout every hour.

Comment: @abraham hehe, that's what I ended up using after your first comment.  I set a timer to check every 10 minutes to re-run 'getAuthToken' and issue a new one if needed.  I wonder why chrome://identity-internals gives wrong expiration time of the token compared to its real life.  The token is valid for at least 20 minutes after it says it expires in chrome://identity-internals/  Thanks for the help!